# Is there a way in Java Generics to say "T extends Thing or T extends SomethingElse"?

Tags: java, generics

In Java I can say `class SomeClass<T extends Thing>`. But is there a way to say that I want `T` to extend either `Thing` or `SomethingElse`?

Comment: No there is not. imagine you are a compiler. How would you type check when you call a method which is not in both Thing and SomethingElse. Can you add an interface with the methods you need or can you spilt your method/class

Comment: No, there is not. Generics must unify.

Comment: And how would `<X extends String | Runnable>` work if I did `final X x = getx()` and tried to call methods on `x`?

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Easy, the concrete call-site (or further refinement) gets to pick "the thing". As long as the unified (read: used) structural type signatures are preserved there is no problem, but this is not Java which is based entirely on nominative types. (That is, the task itself is not impossible by any means and C++ shows this on the other extreme with templates.)

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen So there is no way to build a container class, that can be set to work only either with `Integer` or with `String` for example?

Comment: Why don't you let `Thing` and `SomethingElse` implement the same interface? Or make a class like `QVariant` in C++?

Comment: @avivcohn if you just need to store and return you don't need any restrictions at al.

Comment: @avivcohn I'm curious why you need that restriction.

Comment: but you could make the class abstract and inherit two implementations that make T concrete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Java as proposed - Java does not supported [algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Java Generic type restrictions *must unify* to a single type just as expressions in Java *must unify* to a single type - eg. it is invalid for the same reason as trying to use<sup>1</sup>:

```
{ArrayList | HashSet} collection = ..;
```

However, since they both these types *unify* at Collection then the following is valid:

```
Collection collection = createArrayListOrHashSetAndReturnACollection();
```

Now, depending on need there are two general ways in which is task *may* be handled, both going back to the above limitations:

1. The types in question can extend (or better, inherit) from a common type and can then *unify* around that type. This may involve modification of the types in question as required.
2. A different type (backed by an interface, probably using composition) can be created that acts as a *proxy* for the Thing/SomethingElse types. The generic restriction now *unifies* on this new type/interface.
3. Remove the type restriction and *unify* around Object; this is the least refined unification of every non-primitive type in Java.

---

<sup>1</sup> While this is not a restriction of "OOP", generics/templates, or static type-systems in general, this *is* how Java works: nope, can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

in fact there is a very well known encoding of algebraic data types in Java. It is called the visitor Pattern. And there is even a compile time solution to simplify the implementation of this pattern: see the project adt4j on Github.

But what you are looking for is [Generalized algebraic data type (GADT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_algebraic_data_type).

Turns out that Java also support GADT (and without type-casting). See this gist as an example of an elegant solution to the expression problem using GADT: https://gist.github.com/jbgi/208a1733f15cdcf78eb5 -- In this code we define the class Term where T is statically constrained to be either Integer or Boolean.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this

```
public abstract class SomeClass<T>{

}

public class StringSomeClass : SomeClass<String>{

}

public class IntegerSomeClass : SomeClass<Integer>{

}
```

Answer (score -4):

No, there isn't. In every object oriented language a class can extend only one class.

Instead, you may want to use something like: 
MyClassOne extends Something 
MyClassTwo extends SomethingElse

if (...)
MyClassOne
else
MyClassTwo

Comment: Don't speak for "every" language so casually, as the answer is *wrong* in doing so. Also, OOP languages *can* support non-nominative types as well. Now the question *is* about Java and using the proper (not "every") context *can*, and should, be used to define the behavior in the particular context.

Comment: @user2864740 Don't be so harsh on him. People make mistakes.

Comment: @AvivCohn I don't find it so harsh (after my revisions); nor did I even down-vote. Rather it explains one of the core problems with the answer, how to correct it, any why it was mercilessly down-voted.

Comment: @user2864740 - I didn't mean it bad, althouogh it may have not sounded like it... I also learned the hard way :)